# Questions on combinations.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Q. A candidate taking a mathematics paper is told to answer 5 of the 7 questions in section A, and 3 questions from the 5 options(each option consists of 3 questions) in Section B, where not more than 2 questions from the same option can be chosen. Assuming that he answers 8 questions altogether, find how many different combinations of questions he could attempt.
ANSWER: 9450

MY ANSWER:4410
MY WORKING:
section A = 7C5 = 21
section B:
3 OPTIONS (1+1+1) = 5C3 x 3 = 30
for the above 5C3 is 3 options chosen out of 5. I multiplied by 3 because 1 question is chosen out of 3 for each option.\

2 OPTIONS (2+1) = 5C1 x 3C2 x 4C1 x 3C1 = 180
5C1 is choosing 1 option where 2 questions will be attempted.
3C2 is the possibilities of 2 questions attempted out of 3.
4C1 is the remaining possibilities for choosing the 2nd option where one question will be attempted.
3C1 is the possibilities of 1 question attempted out of 3.\

total = 210 for section B
210 x 21 = 4410

Please explain whether my answer is wrong and why.

Comment: Please format your question with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Ricky No thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an error when you selected one question from each of three options in section B.  There are indeed $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to select three of the five options from which to select a question.  Since there are three ways to choose a question for each option, you should have multiplied by $3^3$ rather than $3$.  Notice that
$$\binom{7}{5}\left[\binom{5}{3}3^3 + \binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\right] = 9450$$

Notice also that there are $\binom{15}{3}$ ways to select three of the fifteen questions in section B without restriction.  However, we are prohibited from answering all three questions from the same option.   There are $\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{3}$ ways to answer three questions from the same option.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{15}{3} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{3}$$
admissible ways to select the questions in section B.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{7}{5}\left[\binom{15}{3} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{3}\right] = 9450$$
admissible ways to answer five questions from section A and three questions from section B.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that. I'll also try the other approach you showed in future questions which I knew but never quite used. I think it is also a good way to verify my answers in the exams tomorrow. If you have any advice I'd be happy to hear it!